# How to use eval to evaluate a list containing Boolean logic expression in scheme/racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, eval, boolean-logic

After defining expression:

```
(define expr1 '(and #t #f))
```

Tried:

```
(eval expr1)
```

Error returned:
"and: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: and"

How to eval expr1?

Comment: You don't have the namespace set up. Try it in a namespace like one created by `(make-base-namespace)`

Comment: Are namespaces similar to the notion of environments in SICP?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how environments are used in SICP. For Racket, namespaces are introduced in the [Namespaces section of the Racket Guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html#(part._namespaces)).